# (node:199408) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hi im new to codding and is wondering what my code would change to with the pass a function instead here is my already existing code with the error

```
let reportschannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "reports");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation you could find useful to read: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find

So, your code would become:

```
let reportschannel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "reports");
```